# Is it possible to run 32 bit program (IonCube) on 64 bit Solaris (SmartOS)?

Tags: solaris, ioncube, joyent, smartos

I am extremely new to the Solaris world however we are attempting to utilize SmartOS which is made by Joyent for the purposes of web hosting. First problem we run into almost immediately: Our client's eCommerce site uses an extension that is encoded with IonCube. IonCube currently only supports x86 and sparc.

http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php

The extension in use cannot be substituted without a week of migration work installing an alternative. Is there any way to package or run IonCube x86 as x86-64? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If this isn't possible, I'm also open to alternatives that allow the 3rd party developer to encode their extension's PHP and allow us to decode it using Solaris x86_64. The most affordable solution thus far is phpSHIELD: http://www.phpshield.com/loaders/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix 32 bit and 64 bit code. It looks like ioncube is not a program but a shared library. It then requires to be linked with a 32 bit binary.

On the other hand, a 64 bit Solaris kernel supports running either 32 or 64 bit binaries so what you might do is to make sure you use a 32 bit version of your main application, if available.

Comment: That seems to be the case. The IonCube installer outputs the 3 following errors when I attempt to run the 32 bit version on the 64 bit Solaris:

The necessary zend_extension line could not be found in the configuration.

The loader file found at /opt/local/share/httpd/htdocs/ioncube/ioncube_loader_sun_5.3.so is not the correct one for your system.

You have the wrong loader for your operating system, .